# JQuery Popup - Ipad/Tablet Numeric Key Board

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to pop up Numeric Keybarod when user clicks on text box, using jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the input type to "tel", browsers that support it will show a numeric key board.

```
<input type="tel">
```

If you then add a check (e.g. using Modernizr) to provide a fallback solution for browser that don't support it natively, you can use a plugin like this one:
http://www.jqueryfun.com/2010/06/23/numeric-keypad-to-allow-only-numbers-into-input-fields/

```
if ( ! Modernizr.inputtypes.tel) {
    // Custom plugin
}
```

Comment: Thanks Geert, will try your suggestion.